# MD5 hash with seed in PHP

Tags: php, c, md5

I am trying to replicate in PHP a part of code written in C. Here is the original source code.

```
MD5Init( &ctx, seed );
MD5Update( &ctx, data, len );
MD5Final( &ctx );
```

I tried to generate the same MD5 hash with the following PHP code :

```
$ctx = hash_init('md5', HASH_HMAC, $seed);
hash_update($ctx, $str);
$hash = hash_final($ctx);
```

I am using the same string and seed in both cases but the resulting hash is different. Is there any reason why this happens? How can I generate the same hash result obtained in C?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean? I tried to generate the same MD5 hash by using hash_init(), hash_update() and hash_final() but it does not seem to generate the same hash as MD5Init(), MD5Update() and MD5Final()...

Comment: in php you do not need `hash_init`, a simple `MD5('string to hash');` will do.

Comment: Yes but it won't generate the same hash as the one generated from the C function... My goal is to end up with the exact same hash generated in C (which uses a seed).

Comment: Did you consider the encoding of the strings?

Comment: In C the data type of the string to hash is unsigned char *data . In my PHP script it's a string. For the seed it is hardcoded as an hex value in both cases. Let me know if this might be the source of my problem...

Comment: try hard-coded hex values for both (C and PHP) strings..

Comment: Where did you get the C code from? Standard `MD5Init()` only takes one argument.

Comment: 1) `MD5Init` does not take a "seed", 2) You've requested a `HMAC` in PHP, not normal md5, and that takes a "key", not a "seed"